# XAML automatic code generation not working after editing .csproj file

Tags: c#, wpf

My project was originally an old .NET Framework 4.5 project and I was trying to migrate to 4.6.1 and add a reference to a .NET Standard 2 library. So I edited the `csproj` file and replaced its contents with the following:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Extended.Wpf.Toolkit" Version="3.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="FFME.Windows" Version="4.0.270" />
    <PackageReference Include="FontAwesome5" Version="1.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="SevenZipSharp.Net45" Version="1.0.19" />
    <PackageReference Include="WindowsAPICodePack" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="PresentationCore" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationFramework" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Presentation" />
    <Reference Include="WindowsBase" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I have used this method in the past to migrate non-WPF Windows-based projects to have new project structure and it works as long as WPF is not used; but wherever `XAML` is involved, the auto-generated partial classes are missing. How can I get this to work?

Comment: You want to compare .csproj generated by wpf template in vs and your current project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lost some important properties and some important items in your csproj file.

### If you target .NET Framework:

You should add a `LanguageTargets` property, and if you lost it WPF XAML files will not build.

Then copy the items below to include all your XAML files, resource files and setting files.

It's recommended to copy the code below to your csproj file and add your own other items.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net47</TargetFramework>

        <!-- Important! You've lost it. -->
        <LanguageTargets>$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets</LanguageTargets>

        <!-- If this is not the main exe project, Remove it. -->
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>

    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>

        <!-- App.xaml -->
        <ApplicationDefinition Include="App.xaml" SubType="Designer" Generator="MSBuild:Compile" />

        <!-- XAML elements -->
        <Page Include="**\*.xaml" Exclude="App.xaml" SubType="Designer" Generator="MSBuild:Compile" />
        <Compile Update="**\*.xaml.cs" DependentUpon="%(Filename)" />

        <!-- Resources -->
        <EmbeddedResource Update="Properties\Resources.resx" Generator="ResXFileCodeGenerator" LastGenOutput="Resources.Designer.cs" />
        <Compile Update="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs" AutoGen="True" DependentUpon="Resources.resx" DesignTime="True" />

        <!-- Settings -->
        <None Update="Properties\Settings.settings" Generator="SettingsSingleFileGenerator" LastGenOutput="Settings.Designer.cs" />
        <Compile Update="Properties\Settings.Designer.cs" AutoGen="True" DependentUpon="Settings.settings" />

    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="PresentationCore" />
        <Reference Include="PresentationFramework" />
        <Reference Include="System.Xaml" />
        <Reference Include="WindowsBase" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

### If you target WPF on .NET Core:

Your csproj file will be much simpler.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
    <PropertyGroup>

        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
        <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>

        <!-- If this is not the main exe project, Remove it. -->
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>

    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

### Tips

You may want to add more application properties in your `<PropertyGroup />`:

```
<PropertyGroup>

    <!-- If you have App.manifest, add this here. -->
    <!-- <ApplicationManifest>Properties\App.manifest</ApplicationManifest> -->

    <!-- f you have App.ico, add this here. -->
    <!-- <ApplicationIcon>Properties\App.ico</ApplicationIcon> -->

    <!-- If you have another startup object instead of App.xaml, change it to it. -->
    <StartupObject />

</PropertyGroup>
```

### Posts

The csproj file content above are posted on my sites:

- [将 WPF、UWP 以及其他各种类型的旧 csproj 迁移成基于 Microsoft.NET.Sdk 的新 csproj - walterlv](https://walterlv.com/post/introduce-new-style-csproj-into-net-framework.html)
- [将基于 .NET Framework 的 WPF 项目迁移到基于 .NET Core 3 - walterlv](https://walterlv.com/post/migrate-wpf-project-from-dotnet-framework-to-dotnet-core.html)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with not including `Page` tags from the old `.csproj` file.
This is how the new `.csproj` file looks like:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Extended.Wpf.Toolkit" Version="3.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="FFME.Windows" Version="4.0.270" />
    <PackageReference Include="FontAwesome5" Version="1.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="SevenZipSharp.Net45" Version="1.0.19" />
    <PackageReference Include="WindowsAPICodePack" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="PresentationCore" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationFramework" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Presentation" />
    <Reference Include="WindowsBase" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Page Include="MainWindow.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    ...
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Now it's working like a charm!